# Assign A Value Of Null In Java

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to assign `null` to a `dateObj`, but I'm not sure if this is the way to do it:

[image]

Comment: No, `dateObj.getDay();` doesn't set `dateObj` to null. What made you think it would?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply write:

```
dateObj = null;
```

N.B: Remember all references can take the value null.